# Scrolling a video remotely?

Tags: video, scroll, frames

How do I scroll a video hosted on a remote site. I need to write up a program that has the ability to scroll a video and download a particular set of frames. The hosting site will expose the video and my program will connect to the site and consume the video.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't after a HD quality a simple screen recording software might do the trick for you.
There are many available on-line, for example: [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/)

Comment: I am going to write my own code. I won't be using third party softwares, unless i find a library that does what I mentioned in my question